# VBA for filtering a pivot table field based on named range

Tags: excel, vba, range, pivot-table

I have a dynamic named range and 2 pivot tables (from the same source table) - PivotTable3 & PivotTable4.

I need to filter both based on the values in the named range.

At the moment I am trying the following but the result of running the macro is just to clear all filters.

Thank you!

```
Sub FilterPivot()
    Dim PI As PivotItem
    With Worksheets("Front").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("[KS].[MN].[MN]")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each PI In .PivotItems
            PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("NamedRange"), PI.Name) > 0
        Next PI
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the values, for example adding `Debug.Print PI.Name & " : " & (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("NamedRange"), PI.Name) > 0)` in the loop??

Comment: Try to set more specific directory for `Range("NamedRange")` for example `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Front").Range("NamedRange")`